# printing the multiplication of two array using dynamic memory

Tags: c++

i tried printing a dynamic array which will consist of multiplication of two array but the out output is only saving only the last multiplication only to all its memory places

```
Example 

int a [] {1,2};
int b {} {10,20};

so output memory is showing {40,40,40,40}
where it should show {10,20,20,40}
```

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int Print(size_t size, int arr[])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int *apply_all (int arr1[] , size_t size1 , int arr2[] ,size_t size2)
{
    int *new_storage {nullptr};
    new_storage = new int[size1 * size2];
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < size2 ; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < size1 ; j++)
        {
            for(size_t k = 0; k < size1 * size2 ; k++)
            {
                *(new_storage + k ) = arr1[j] * arr2[i];
            }
        }

    }
    return new_storage;
}  

int main()
{
    int array1[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    int array2[] {10,20,30};
    int *new_array {nullptr};
    Print(5,array1);
    Print(3,array2);
    cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"After Applying "<<endl;

    new_array = apply_all(array1,5,array2,3);
    Print(15,new_array);
    delete [] new_array;
    return 0;


}
```

Here is The Output:

**

> 1 2 3 4 5 10 20 30
>   -------------------------------------------------- After Applying 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 150 Press any key
>   to continue . . .

**
Any Help Will be highly appreciated

Comment: Hint: in your most inner loop, i and j are constant.

Comment: Replace the raw pointers with vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the innermost loop, as it is not really needed

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size1; j++) {
        new_storage[i + j * size2] = arr1[j] * arr2[i];
    }
}
```